# springboot : how to return error status code in prehandle of HandlerInterceptor

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am using `HandlerInterceptor` in Spring Boot for processing common types of requests.
But while executing `preHandle`, I want to return error status code to user if conditions are not met.
If i throw the exception inside `preHandle` the response will have all the exception stack.
How to send custom body as response with response code from preHandle

Comment: By calling the appropriate methods on the `response` parameter object. Which part of that would not be clear from the definition of the [`preHandle()`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerInterceptor.html#preHandle-javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest-javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse-java.lang.Object-) method?

Answer (score 38):

If conditions are not met, you can use `response.setStatus(someErrorCode)` to set the response status code and return `false` to stop execution. To send custom body you can use the following method:           `response.getWriter().write("something");`

Here is the full example.

```
@Override
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
    HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {

    if (conditionsNotMet()) {
        response.getWriter().write("something");
        response.setStatus(someErrorCode);

        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: still the body is not visible , i am only seeing statuscode.
Am i doing anything wrong

Comment: What do you mean body is not visible?

Comment: I mean i didnt get anything in response except status as errorcode that is send

Comment: When you use this method `response.getWriter().write("something");`, you'll get "something" message in the response body

Comment: i am getting default msg "error" instead of "something"(custom exception msg). Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could someone elaborate on the `stop execution` part of this answer? Will it not go through any additional `HandlerInterceptor`'s if marked false? Will it not make it to the handler itself if marked false?

Comment: @CopyandPaste before getting to the actual controller, spring will call all the interceptors in the order you specified to it. If a preHandler interceptor returns false, it doesnt call anything else and return what you specified it to return via the HttpServletResponse object